# Subquery on Join - Where statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been stuck on this issue for a while now. The problem is the following :

I have 3 tables. A students table, a payments table and a pivot course_student table. 
A student can take many courses and each student can make many payments for each course they take. This data is stored on my payments table with a reference to course_student_id.

I just need the last payment made by the student which holds the latest information about the student's payment.

Here's my query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM payments p
JOIN course_student cs ON cs.id = p.course_student_id
JOIN students s ON s.id = cs.student_id
GROUP BY p.course_student_id
HAVING max(p.id) IN ( SELECT id FROM payments )
```

The problem is that I'm getting back only the first record of each course_student from the payments table when actually I expect the last row.

Here's an example of what I want returned :

```
Students
student_name student_id course_student_id
XYZ                   1                 1
```

On the payments table, say I have 3 entries for course_student_id = 1

```
Payments
 id course_student_id amount_paid
 1                  1         100
 2                  1         250
 3                  1         500
```

I need the query to return all of the details of the last payment.

Comment: I don't understand your `HAVING` clause, `MAX(payments.id)` will always be `IN` `payments.id`

Comment: Now that you said it, you're right. So what do you think is a better way?

Comment: Add sample table data and expected result!

Comment: I think you already have an answer from @vkp. Remember though, if you use aggregate functions (`MAX`, `SUM`, `AVG` etc) always specify your `GROUP BY`, and don't `SELECT` what is not in your `GROUP BY` or in an aggregate function. `mysql` allows it, but it's wrong

Comment: Presumably 'latest' is the one with the highest id?

Comment: What is a course_student_id anyway?

Comment: @Strawberry, course_student_id is the id that uniquely identifies the student and the course he / she is taking. course_student is a pivot of courses and students (many to many relationship)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider trying this solution. The subselect creates a new list of all the students payments for each course_student_id, and selects out the largest id.

```
SELECT * 
FROM payments p
JOIN course_student cs ON cs.id = p.course_student_id
JOIN students s ON s.id = cs.student_id
WHERE p.id in (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM payments p2
    WHERE p2.course_student_id = p.course_student_id)
```

Comment: exactly what I need. Thanks so much. I did the exact same query a million times and the only thing I was missing was the 'WHERE p2.course_student_id = p.course_student_id'

Comment: @vjrngn Note that vkp's solution will be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: I see. I tried it .. could you repost / reply using the combination of the two answers ?

Comment: @vjrngn Seems more fun to leave that as an exercise for the reader. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a derived table to get the max date for a student's payment. If the max date should be by course, include it in `group by`.

```
SELECT s.id, t.course_id, t.mxdate --other columns as needed
FROM course_student cs
JOIN students s ON s.id = cs.student_id
JOIN (select course_student_id, course_id, max(payment_date) as mxdate from payments
                                 ---^ --        ^ --change these columns to be appropriate
      group by course_student_id, course_id) t
on t.course_student_id = s.id
```

Comment: Here I'm interested in the latest payment for a course, so I would query on the payments table. I did that but get the grouped student records correctly but only the first payment record and not the last. I hope that made sense

Comment: it would help if you could post some sample data

Comment: @vjrngn I agree with vkp that you should sample input data (data from your tables) and based on that data include what output you need.

Comment: @vkp, thanks for the query. But that actually returns an empty set. No results were found.

Comment: the query posted was based on guess work. Unless you post sample data it is difficult to answer without even knowing the column names

Comment: I understand. Sample data with column names posted.

Answer (score 0):

How about simplifying it and using `limit` and `order by` to get the latest payment information?

```
SELECT * 
FROM payments p
JOIN course_student cs ON cs.id = p.course_student_id
JOIN students s ON s.id = cs.student_id
ORDER BY p.id desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I tried that. I get back only a single row, not surprisingly as limit works on the entire data set returned and not on the group by